# Django default form: populate some fields with values from last saved object

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using Django to record game sessions. A session has a time, place, league and game for example. At one sitting I may need to record many played games. I a create form for the session, I can enter these comfortably now and all is good.

The problem is on one sitting all the games are typically at the same place in the same league for example and around the same time so I'd like after saving one form, to be presented with a new create form, in which the place, league and time are already set to sensible defaults (same place and league as the last save and maybe same time plus 90mins).

I'm not sure of the best way to approach this. The session data store seems attractive, but is rather limited by the fact that each of these needs to JSON serializable to store there.

I'm thinking maybe I can pull the info out of the database, and for example in the view's context add a copy of the last such object saved. But somehow I have to use that context to populate the default for which is only in my template as:

```
{{ form.as_table }}
```

and I love that it's so simple, I don't want to break it out and design a form if I don't have to. Is there a way to keep it that simple and see the individual fields default to some value based on the previous submission?

I'm struggling to think of an easy way.

As this strikes me as a use case that is not likely novel or new, and others have probably tackled, I wanted to table the question first before I think much deeper about it.

Is this a solved problem? Is there a canonical Django approach to populating a default form that the CreateView class produces? The UpdateView populates that same default form with the fields of an instance provided to it. And the CreateView respects defaults specified in the model definition. But is there a canonical approach to populating a CreateView in part with defaults that are determined at load time.

My suspicion is it would need deriving a new class from CreateView and overriding get_initial(). But I can't seem to find much clear documentation on it or good examples and as noted, wonder if this is not a solved problem with a canonical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, overriding `get_initial` is exactly the right thing to do. For example:

```
class CreateNewSession(views.CreateView):
    model = Session
    ....

    def get_initial(self):
        last = Session.objects.order_by('-created')[0]
        return {
            'place': last.place,
            'league': last.league,
            'time': last.time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=90)
        }
```